# openmp shared or nothing. private vs uninitialized

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp

Is there a difference between these two implementations of openmp?

```
float dot_prod (float* a, float* b, int N)
{
float sum = 0.0;
#pragma omp parallel for shared(sum)
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  #pragma omp critical
  sum += a[i] * b[i];
  }
return sum;
}
```

and the same code but line 4 doesn't have the shared(sum) because sum is already initialized?

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int = 0; ....)
```

Same question for private in openmp:

Is

```
void work(float* c, int N)
{
float x, y; int i;
#pragma omp parallel for private(x,y)
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
  x = a[i]; y = b[i];
  c[i] = x + y;
  }
}
```

the same as without the private(x,y) because x and y aren't initialized?

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

Comment: The rules that apply have nothing to do with whether variables are initialized or not. [Shared and private variables in a parallel environment](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbcpx01/cuppvars.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a difference between these two implementations of openmp?

```
float dot_prod (float* a, float* b, int N)
{
  float sum = 0.0;
# pragma omp parallel for shared(sum)
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    #pragma omp critical
    sum += a[i] * b[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

In openMP a variable declared outside the parallel scope is `shared`, unless it is explicitly rendered `private`.
Hence the `shared` declaration  can be omitted.

But your code is far from being optimal. It works, but will be by far slower than its sequential counterpart, because `critical` will force sequential processing and creating a critical section  has an important temporal cost.

The proper implementation would use a `reduction`.

```
float dot_prod (float* a, float* b, int N)
{
  float sum = 0.0;
# pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    sum += a[i] * b[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

The reduction creates a hidden local variable to accumulate in parallel in every thread and before thread destruction performs an atomic addition of these local sums on the shared variable `sum`.

> Same question for private in openmp:

```
void work(float* c, int N)
{
  float x, y; int i;
# pragma omp parallel for private(x,y)
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    x = a[i]; y = b[i];
    c[i] = x + y;
  }
}
```

By default, `x` and `y` are shared. So without  `private` the behaviour will be different (and buggy because all threads will modify the same globally accessible vars `x` and `y` without an atomic access).

> the same as without the private(x,y) because x and y aren't initialized?

Initialization of `x` and `y` does not matter, what is important is where they are declared. To insure proper behavior, they must be rendered private and the code will be correct as `x`and `y` are set before been used in the loop.

Comment: The answer is good in general, but one issue: `sum` is **not** a *global variable*, but a local variable declared outside the parallel scope. I would also emphasize that the *declaration* matters, not the initialization.

Comment: You are right. Sum is a local variable globally accessible by the threads as declared outside the parallel scope. The term 'global' is frequently found in openmp literature as a synonym for shared, to describe this kind of vars, but it is incorrect. I fix the answer.